# Как остановить таймер на сервере nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

перепробовал уже все методы, не могу остановить таймер на сервере nodejs. Пробовал разные варианты и с setInterval и setTimeout. Получаю всегда дальше работающий таймер.

```
function myTimer(room,step){
    holand.get(room, function(err, reply) {
        console.log(reply);
        var newcena = reply - step;
        console.log('New price '+newcena);
        holand.set(room, newcena);
        socket.emit('iscena', newcena.toFixed(2));
    });
}

var timerId;
console.log('1 '+timerId);

socket.on('howcena', function(data){
    var room = data.room;
    var step = data.step;
    console.log(room);
    console.log(step);
    timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
      myTimer(room,step);
      timerId = setTimeout(tick, 5000);
    }, 5000);
    console.log('2 '+timerId);

});
socket.on('stopcena',function(data){
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    console.log('3 '+timerId);
    console.log('Stop timer');
});
```

Comment: Какой из двух таймеров Вы  не можете остановить?

Comment: @Дмытрык Нужно остановить оба таймера, нет принципиальной разницы, в случаи с setInterval пытался остановить но не получилось, возможно в случаи с setTimeout  я не правильно пытаюсь это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
var timerId;
function myTimer(room,step){
  holand.get(room, function(err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
    var newcena = reply - step;
    console.log('New price '+newcena);
    holand.set(room, newcena);
    socket.emit('iscena', newcena.toFixed(2));
  });
}

function tick() {
  myTimer(room,step);
  if (timerId) {
    timerId = setTimeout(tick, 5000);
  }
}
console.log('1 '+timerId);

socket.on('howcena', ({ room, step }) => {
  console.log(room);
  console.log(step);
  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 5000);
  console.log('2 '+timerId);
});

socket.on('stopcena', () => {
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = null;
  console.log('3 '+timerId);
  console.log('Stop timer');
});
```

Проблема в том что `clearTimeout` остановит таймер только после последнего выполнения функции, в которой нет никакого условия преграждающего запуск следующего таймера. Решение ― написать какое-то условие чтобы не запускать таймер.